# Не получается динамически порождать на окне кнопки или метки

Tags: c#, winforms

Написать программу, динамически порождающую на окне
кнопки или метки. Левый верхний угол элемента управления определяется местоположением курсора при щелчке. При нажатии правой кнопки мыши на форме с нее удаляются все кнопки.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace laba5
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {



        }

        private void Form1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) 
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                Label label = new Label();
                label.Location = e.Location;
                label.Size = new Size(rnd.Next(150, 200), rnd.Next(150, 200));
                Button button = new Button();
                button.Location = e.Location;
                button.Size = new Size(rnd.Next(50, 100), rnd.Next(50, 100));
               
            }
            else if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
            {
                Controls.Clear();
            }
        }

        private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show((sender as Button).Text);
        }
    }


    
}
```

Вроде написал все по учебнику, а при запуске не работает, что правая, что левая кнопка

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну, как минимум Вы их просто не добавляете.

Для того, что бы добавить контрол на форму, необходимо было сделать

```
this.Controls.Add(имя_контрола);
```

Второй момент, даже если Вы добавите этот код, label не будет отображаться, т.к. вы не задали ему текст (он будет в списке контролов, но визуально его не будет видно).

```
label.Text = "текст";
```

Ну и последний момент - великоваты размеры `label`, он "перекрывает" кнопку. Логики зачем Вам такое нужно я не понимаю, если нужно задать текст кнопке - используйте свойство `Text`.

+- рабочий итог:

```
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                Label label = new Label();
                label.Location = e.Location;
                label.Size = new Size(rnd.Next(50, 50), rnd.Next(50, 50));
                label.Text = "1231231";
                Button button = new Button();
                button.Location = e.Location;
                button.Size = new Size(rnd.Next(50, 100), rnd.Next(50, 100));
                this.Controls.Add(label);
                this.Controls.Add(button);
            }
```

Comment: только хотел написать тоже самое)

Comment: @KuzCode такие вопросы - как горячие пирожки)

Comment: Спасибо большое, я не так давно начал учить c# просто 